# Objective C - how to get current screen resolution?

Tags: objective-c, screen, resolution, screen-resolution

is there any way to get the users screen resolution with objective c?

Thanks.

Solution:

```
int width = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width;
int height = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [NSScreen](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: What about when the scale preference is changed in settings on a mac? [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width still returns the same thing even if the number of pixels changes

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589198/how-to-read-the-physical-screen-size-of-osx…

Answer (score 1):

[UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds

Comment: Please add explanations if needed when you add answers.