# Get screen resolution programmatically in OS X

Tags: c++, macos, core-graphics, fullscreen

I'd like to launch a fullscreen 3D C++ application in native resolution on mac.
How can I retrieve the native screen resolution ?

Comment: Ideally, there should be an API function (e.g. `fullscreenize()`), which would do all the handling for you. Then you'd just use your window's size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C  - how to get current screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868677/objective-c-how-to-get-current-screen-resolution)

Comment: does the solution need to be just C++, or is Obj-C acceptable?

Comment: @middaparka: That is not a duplicate. The OP clearly specifies C++- the other question clearly specifies Objective C.

Comment: @DeadMG Good point - my bad. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't wish to use Objective C, get the display ID that you wish to display on (using e.g. [`CGMainDisplayID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGMainDisplayID)), then use [`CGDisplayPixelsWide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayPixelsWide) and [`CGDisplayPixelsHigh`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayPixelsHigh) to get the screen width and height, in pixels. See "[Getting Information About Displays](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/DisplayInfo.html)" for how to get other display information.

If you're willing to use a bit of Objective-C, simply use [`[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/DisplayInfo.html).

Note that there are other concerns with full screen display, namely ensuring other applications don't do the same. Read "[Drawing to the Full Screen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html)" in Apple's OpenGL Programming Guide for more.

Comment: NSScreen mainScreen will not necessarily return the "mainScreen" - the size seems to depend on other things... possibly the last selected window? At any rate it doesn't provide consistent results in practice

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a multiplatform solution for both mac and windows

```
#include "ScreenSize.h"

#if WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <CoreGraphics/CGDisplayConfiguration.h>
#endif

void ScreenSize::getScreenResolution(unsigned int& width, unsigned int& height) {
#if WIN32
    width = (int)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    height = (int)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
#else
    auto mainDisplayId = CGMainDisplayID();
    width = CGDisplayPixelsWide(mainDisplayId);
    height = CGDisplayPixelsHigh(mainDisplayId);
#endif
}
```

Note: You also need to link the CoreGraphics framework to your project.
If you are using cmake, link your needed framework like the following:

```
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        "-framework CoreGraphics"
        "-framework Foundation"
    )
```