# View bounds and coordinates in Cocoa Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a simple custom view in my Mac OS X application that is essentially empty. Here is the code:

```
@implementation MyDrawingView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSLog(@"bounds:x:%f y:%f w:%f h:%f", self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
}

@end
```

Here is the output of NSLog:

```
bounds:x:0.000000 y:0.000000 w:713.000000 h:509.000000
```

I read about user space here: [Coordinate Systems and Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCIDJJBI)

Does this mean that my view is going to show 713/72 inches wide on screen? It doesn't show up that wide in reality. I have a background color set on my view so I can see it just as wide as it really is.

Comment: To see anything you have to activate drawing. You are missing [super drawRect:dirtyRect].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the view is 713 points wide. 713*screenscale = pixel size which you can then use with dpi to get the inches shown ;)

Comment: a)Where do you get screenscale from and b)what does it mean to say that user space is fixed 72points/inch?

Comment: a) on osx you get the scale for your processnfrom your NSWindow's backingScale property

Comment: b) thats what you said "713/72 inches wide on screen?" -- I therefore assumed that you knew you had a display with 72dpi (if you don't have the dpi. use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589198/how-to-read-the-physical-screen-size-of-osx)